# Salesforce CPQ Translation output language - English doesn't appear

Tags: cpq, translation, quote-template

In the UAT, I deployed CPQ's records, including localization records. Quote Term's English translation does not work, so I tried to redo it. On the quote term record, I selected the "*Translate*" action, but the "**English**" language was not listed.

[image: CPQ Translation output language - English doesn't appear]

Is there a way to solve this? Can anyone suggest a solution?

Thanks

***UPDATE***

I've changed the organization's default language from English to German (Setup > Company Information > Default Language) and "English" has been added to the output language list.

Comment: UPDATE

I've changed the organization's default language from English to German (Setup > Company Information > Default Language) and "English" has been added to the output language list.

Comment: You should post this as an answer so it is clearer for others what solution is.

Comment: Done it. I appreciate your suggestion, @DanielHoechst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE I've changed the organization's default language from English to German (Setup > Company Information > Default Language) and "English" has been added to the output language list.